# Azure Load balancer traffic distribution

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, load-balancing

I have a standard load balancer deployed with a backend pool consisting of two servers, inbound rule - 443. We have session persistence selected with Client IP. I want to know if by doing this all the traffic will go to only one server on which the client session was established first? does the affinity established between the client IP and backend servers expire or it is permanent(i.e all traffic from that particular client will go to the original server).

n my case Idle timeout is set to default 4 mins but all traffic from client is being routed to one server lets say server A and nothing is going to server B. only when A is down or rebooted the traffic is routed to A. When A is up all traffic again goes back to A. is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session persistence means that requests from the same source IP to the same destination IP will go to the same server on your backend (if you use the three-tuple option, then it is the same source, destination and protocol).

This will persist so long as the server is up and no servers are added or removed from the load balancer. Adding or removing a machine will result in a re-calculation of the rules, and this may change where requests go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I get it now. So now changing the session persistence to none is the only way for me to make traffic distributed evenly among backend server?

Comment: Yes, if you want an even distribution of traffic, then turn off session persistence.